DB2 substring not using length properly
I have the following SQL which calculates the length between a start position and end position and then tries to use the start position and length to extract the substring but the substring function uses the start position but seems to ignore the length.
Select --PMREF_REFERENCE,IOMSG_RECEIVER, IOMSG_SENDER, IOMSG_FORMAT,    
         posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/')  AS "Tag59 St" ,                   
         INSTR(MCONT_DATA, X'0D25', posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/')) AS "@",
         (posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/')) AS "T59 end",                    
         (INSTR(MCONT_DATA, X'0D25', posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/'))       
            - (posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/')) ) AS "len" ,                
-- next should start at pos of tatg 59 for length - DOESN'T WORK!      
  SUBSTR(substr(MCONT_DATA, posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/') ,               
         (INSTR(MCONT_DATA, X'0D25', posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/'))       
            - (posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/')) )                           
               **), 1, 13**                                                
--         (INSTR(MCONT_DATA, X'0D25', posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/'))     
--            - (posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/')))                          
        ) AS "T59 str"                                                 
--                                                                     
      ,  substr(MCONT_DATA,                                            
                posstr(MCONT_DATA,':57A:') , 15) AS "Tag 57" ,         
          substr(MCONT_DATA,                                           
            posstr(MCONT_DATA,':20:') , 20) AS "Tag 20" ,              
         CASE                                                          
       WHEN posstr(MCONT_DATA,':50A:') > 0                             
         THEN substr(MCONT_DATA,                                       
                posstr(MCONT_DATA,':50A:') + 5, 20)                    
       WHEN posstr(MCONT_DATA,':50F:') > 0                             
          THEN substr(MCONT_DATA,                                      
                 posstr(MCONT_DATA,':50F:') + 5, 20)                   
        END                                                            
        , substr(mcont_data,1,550)                                     
FROM RBS.TPPIOMSG A, RBS.TPPMCONT B, RBS.TPPPMREF C    etc...     

   

and the output looks like :
> Tag59 St            @      T59 end          len  T59 str        Tag 57    
> -------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------
>                                                                           
> -------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------
>      395          408          395           13  :59:/20276668  :57A:RBOSG
>      407          420          407           13  :59:/00650006  :57A:RBOSG
>      388          401          388           13  :59:/32882288  :57A:RBOSG
>      409          422          409           13  :59:/10011751  :57A:RBOSG
>      400          413          400           13  :59:/12022717  :57A:RBOSG
>      378          391          378           13  :59:/51435616  :57A:RBOSG
>      407          420          407           13  :59:/00284446  :57A:RBOSG
>

but if I use:
 Select --PMREF_REFERENCE,IOMSG_RECEIVER, IOMSG_SENDER, IOMSG_FORMAT,       
         posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/')  AS "Tag59 St" ,                      
         INSTR(MCONT_DATA, X'0D25', posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/')) AS "@",   
         (posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/')) AS "T59 end",                       
         (INSTR(MCONT_DATA, X'0D25', posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/'))          
            - (posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/')) ) AS "len" ,                   
-- next should start at pos of tatg 59 for length - DOESN'T WORK!         
  SUBSTR(substr(MCONT_DATA, posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/') ,                  
         (INSTR(MCONT_DATA, X'0D25', posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/'))          
            - (posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/')) )                              
--             ), 1, 13                                                   
      **),1, (INSTR(MCONT_DATA, X'0D25', posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/'))        
              - (posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/')))**                             
        ) AS "T59 str"                                                    
                                                                          
      ,  substr(MCONT_DATA,                                               
                posstr(MCONT_DATA,':57A:') , 15) AS "Tag 57" ,            
          substr(MCONT_DATA,                                              
            posstr(MCONT_DATA,':20:') , 20) AS "Tag 20" ,                 
         CASE                                                             
       WHEN posstr(MCONT_DATA,':50A:') > 0                                
         THEN substr(MCONT_DATA,                                          
                posstr(MCONT_DATA,':50A:') + 5, 20)                       
       WHEN posstr(MCONT_DATA,':50F:') > 0                                
          THEN substr(MCONT_DATA,                                         
                 posstr(MCONT_DATA,':50F:') + 5, 20)                      
        END                                                               
        , substr(mcont_data,1,550)                                        
FROM RBS.TPPIOMSG A, RBS.TPPMCONT B, RBS.TPPPMREF C   etc..     

         

gives :
 Tag59 St            @      T59 end          len  T59 str                     
-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
                                                                              
-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
      395          408          395           13  :59:/20276668               
      407          420          407           13  :59:/00650006               
      388          401          388           13  :59:/32882288               
the T59 str is a 4k length! 

Same if I use :
substr(MCONT_DATA, posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/') ,                  
         (INSTR(MCONT_DATA, X'0D25', posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/')) - (posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/')) )                                                                                
          , (INSTR(MCONT_DATA, X'0D25', posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/'))      
              - (posstr(MCONT_DATA,':59:/')))**                             
        ) AS "T59 str" 

                   

It seem the calculation of 'len' works but it doesn't substitute into the substr properly.
Anybody see anything that I
have obviously done wrong?
Many thanks

Sorry that does not answer your question but here is an alternative that works depending on which DB2 you are using : https://dbfiddle.uk/Zf4rCDaw

Thanks but   regexp_substr isn't a valid function in my host DB2 SQL.
